# Mysql UNION with dynamic query

Tags: mysql, dynamic, union

i have the following problem. I inherited a software that uses a database prefix for every customer.
All tables have the same structure and columns. For a data migration to new version i want to union all these tables
 and set a customer foreign key instead and get rid of all the subtables. i'm looking for a way to create 
 a view for this task because i also want to stay backwards compatible for now.
I found this dynamic query which seems to do what i want 
but i can't execute on my mysql server. I assume it was written for another sql server.

The table name structure is (about 80 customer tables):
customer1_faxe
customer2_faxe
customer3_faxe
customer4_faxe
...

How would you approach this problem?

```
DECLARE  @SelectClause  VARCHAR(100)    = 'SELECT *'
        ,@Query         VARCHAR(1000)   = '' 

SELECT @Query = @Query + @SelectClause + ' FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_faxe'

SELECT @Query = LEFT(@Query, LEN(@Query) - LEN(' UNION ALL '))

EXEC (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is using SQL Server syntax.  You need something like this:

```
declare @SelectClause varchar(8000);
declare @Query varchar(8000);

set @SelectClause = 'SELECT *';

SELECT @Query := group_concat(@SelectClause, ' FROM ', TABLE_NAME SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_faxe';

prepare stmt from @Query;
execute stmt;
```

Note that the `group_concat()` with `separator` simplifies the logic.

Comment: First thanks i think this is the right approach. Unfortunately i get "Query was empty" error message. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @bluescreen . . . I believe the `@Query =` in `select` really needs to be `@Query :=`.